# Subdomain hosting on Apache

Tags: apache, redirect, subdomain

I am beginner in web server related stuff.

I have a server already working with the domain `www.example.com`

I want to also host `test.example.com` on the server which would also have the same behavior as `www.example.com`. That is, all the requests to **test.example.com** should be mapped to a start.php file.

Also the domain name should remain `test.example.com`, i.e. I don't want to redirect requests from `test.example.com` to `www.example.com`.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is a [name-based virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/name-based.html).

Specifically, you want to set up a virtual host to direct requests to a specific host (in this case, identified by a subdomain) to a particular directory. Thereafter, just rewrite requests to `start.php`.

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName mysub.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/vhosts/http/mysub.domain.tld

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ start.php [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Place this in your Apache configuration file or into a separate file in the `sites-available` directory, enabling it via `a2ensite`. Make sure this one is loaded before the one for `domain.tld`, or else Apache will recognize the path to `domain.tld` and forget about `mysub.domain.tld`.

Restart Apache, and you should be good to go.

Comment: I needed to add an A record with my DNS registrar as well.